# SQL Server Converting varchar to datetime

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I got a problem in SQL Server with converting a `varchar` to `datetime`. I would like to convert/update whole column `[datelog]` in table:

```
[dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss]` to `[yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss]
```

Comment: Storing datetime values as varchar is a *bug*. You should use the proper field type for the job to avoid conversion, localization and performance issues.

Comment: What culture was used to generate this value? You may be able to use `PARSE` with the same Culture to parse the text to a datetime

Comment: Assuming the text uses the German format, try `select PARSE('24.11.2015 13:10:55' as datetime using 'de-DE')`. Although the *real* solution is to fix the field's type

Comment: Don't edit your questions to ask something different. Your original question was answered. Accept an answer and post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2012+ you can use [PARSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316.aspx) or [TRY_PARSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx) to parse a text value according to a specific culture.

Assuming your text follows the German culture ('de-DE') you can parse it to datetime with :

```
select PARSE('24.11.2015 13:10:55' as datetime using 'de-DE')
```

eg:

```
select PARSE(datelog as datetime using 'de-DE')
```

The real solution though would be to use the *correct* field type, ie `datetime`. It's almost guaranteed that someone, somewhere will either enter text with the wrong format or try to convert the text using the wrong culture.

Date types on the other hand, have no format, they are simply binary values. Using them is faster, safer and easier.

Comment: select PARSE(datelog as datetime using 'de-DE') is working good for me. What if I want to round time on 15 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Tricky solution,

```
DECLARE @inputDate AS VARCHAR(20)='21.11.2015 06:59:00' -- [dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss]
SET @inputDate = REPLACE(@inputDate ,'.' ,'/')
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(24) ,CONVERT(DATETIME ,@inputDate ,103) ,121) OutputDate -- [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss]
```

Still you need to change as per your table columns.

Answer (score 0):

temp table with one column of type varchar

```
create table #temp3 (someDate varchar (30))
insert into #temp3 values ('23.03.1989 15:23:43')
```

using a combination of concat, substring and right

```
select concat
(
SUBSTRING(someDate,7,4),'-', SUBSTRING(someDate,4,2),'-',SUBSTRING(someDate,1,2), ' ', right(someDate, 8)
)
from #temp3
```

gives: 1989-03-23 15:23:43

Comment: if you want dateTime, you can add a cast before concat. ex: `cast(concat (     ) as datetime) as theNewDate from #temp3`